# android - how to develop gps tracker

Tags: android, gps

I'm developing an application that tracks user movment.
I added google map technology and the coordinates im receiving from the server.
My only problem is that i dont know is how to show the way the user is done, or in other words how to show user movment like sport running application.
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You want `Polyline` to show a track on `GoogleMap` map. GoogleMap has `addPolyline` method. See https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

```
 GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 List<LatLng> track;
 // ... get track points.
 // Add a thin red track line.
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .addAll(track)
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```